# R Error - cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'

Tags: r

I'm trying to filter some data, with functions in R relatives to data frames. But in the second function, it gives me the following error: cannot change the value of locked binding for `df`. 
Can anyone help me please?

**Btw, this is the code:**

```
load.data = function(x,dir = ".") {
dados_reais <<- read.csv(paste(dir,x,sep="/"), header = FALSE, sep = "\t", dec = ".", col.names = c("Seq","Allele","Peptide","Identity","Pos","Core","Core-Rel", "Um-log50k(aff)","Affinity(nM)","Rank","Exp_Bind","Binding Level"))
}

filter.data = function(x, dir = ".") {load.data(x, dir) df <<- dados_reais[,c(1,2,3,4,9,10,12)}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be avoiding `<<-`. That creates function with side-effects which run contrary to the spirit of functional languages. Try

```
load.data <- function(x,dir = ".") {
    read.csv(paste(dir,x,sep="/"), header = FALSE, sep = "\t", dec = ".", col.names = c("Seq","Allele","Peptide","Identity","Pos","Core","Core-Rel", "Um-log50k(aff)","Affinity(nM)","Rank","Exp_Bind","Binding Level"))
}

filter.data <- function(x, dir = ".") {
    load.data(x, dir)[,c(1,2,3,4,9,10,12)]
}

df <- filter.data("mypath.csv")
```

Answer (score 51):

### Answer:

The reason is that `<<-` and `<-` work differently.

`x <- val` means "assign the value `val` to the name `x` in the current scope."  That's the assignment operator you should usually use.

`x <<- val` means "go search for a name `x` in the current scope and its enclosing scopes.  As soon as you find it, assign the value `val` to it and stop.  If you don't find it, create a new variable `x` in the broadest scope (global) and assign it the value `val`."

In your case, your name choice of `df` was somewhat unlucky: there's a built-in function `df` (in the `stats` namespace) for computing the density of [Snedecor's F distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution).  Your `<<-` assignment found that, tried to change its value to `dados_reais[,c(1,2,3,4,9,10,12)]`, and refused (because the built-in `df` function is "locked", i.e. immutable).  An easier example showing the issue is this:

```
df <<- 5
# Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'
```

### Incidentally:

As demonstrated, R's variables and functions share the same namespaces (or, more accurately: R's functions are typically stored in the same symbol tables [environments] that all the other variables are, they're not "special" like in many other languages).  So does that mean that you shouldn't ever use a variable like `df` or `min` or `q` or `t`, that clashes with a built-in function's name?  No, generally it's not a big deal, because when you do `min(x)`, R knows to look for a *function* called `min`, not any old symbol table entry called `min`, so it uses something like `get("min", mode="function")` to make sure it doesn't accidentally find some variable you've defined that happens to be called `min`.

That said, sometimes you do get some name collisions that are a little sneaky.  For example, if you *think* you have a `data.frame` called `df`, but you forgot to actually create it, you might see an error like this:

```
df[1, 5]
# Error in df[1, 5] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

It's saying that the function `df` (a function in R is an "object of type 'closure'") can't be indexed with square brackets like that.  File that somewhere in your brain, because if you work with R long enough, you're bound to see that error once in a while.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It offers better explanation about the issue :)

Comment: One of the best answers I found on stackover flow.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, one does want to violate the spirit of functional languages.

I am not sure *why*, in R, a locked *function* prevents you from creating a *variable* at the same level, but the problem the OP has is because the *function* `df()` is locked in an environment above that of the current environment (which `<<-` finds).

Here is some code (probably not the best) to find the environment in which `df` is (already) bound (i.e., already exists), and then check to see if it is, in fact, locked in that environment.

```
> x <- environment(); while(TRUE) { print(exists("df", x)); x <- parent.env(x) }
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
Error in parent.env(x) : the empty environment has no parent
> bindingIsLocked("df", parent.env(parent.env(environment())))
[1] TRUE
>
```

In this case, creating a variable `df` in the "global" context should solve the problem.  i.e.,

```
df <- NULL

filter.data = function(x, dir = ".") {
    load.data(x, dir)
    df <<- dados_reais[,c(1,2,3,4,9,10,12)]
}
```

Alternatively, changing the name of the variable (from `df`, say, to `myveryowndf`) should also fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when creating function inside a package, and I was using `<<-` inside exported function to overwrite some functions from different package. I've created hack with `env <- parent.env()` and adding this to parent env instead since the function was always called at top level. So env will be scope of the code that call the function not the package.

here is complete code of this function, it overwrite shiny and current package functions:

```
#' @export
useMocks <- function() {
  observeEvent <- battery::observeEventMock
  assignInNamespace("observeEvent", observeEvent, "battery")
  assignInNamespace("observeEvent", observeEvent, "shiny")
  isolate <- battery::isolate
  assignInNamespace("isolate", isolate, "shiny")
  makeReactiveBinding <- battery::makeReactiveBinding
  assignInNamespace("makeReactiveBinding", makeReactiveBinding, "shiny")
  renderUI <- battery::renderUI
  assignInNamespace("renderUI", renderUI, "shiny")
  ## we modify the parent frame so it update environment when function is called not the package
  env <- parent.frame()
  env$observeEvent <- observeEvent
  env$isolate <- isolate
  env$renderUI <- renderUI

}
```

using `<<-` throw this error here because you can't modify the package scope.

```
observeEvent <<- battery::observeEventMock
```

this doesn't work

**EDIT**: The whole code was published by the company I was working on (Roche/Genentech) and it's available on GitHub: [Genentech/battery](https://github.com/Genentech/battery)