# R package, How use encapsulated DATA

Tags: r, package, encapsulation

I create a package R with Data encapsulated, but when I try to use this  data in some function but I have this kind of error .

error in (get(".Internal", baseenv()))(delayedAssign(x, value, eval.env,  :
cannot change value of locked binding for 'my_dataset'

The data was encapsulated with the method "usethis::use_data(my_dataset, overwrite = TRUE)"

(sorry for my English ...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! did you try searching this error message? Looks like one way this can come up is using different kinds of assignment operators https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702457/8400969
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56439626/8400969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Error - cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702134/r-error-cannot-change-value-of-locked-binding-for-df)

Comment: This is my first time doing this (I'm still learning Stack Overflow norms as well) but I flagged this question as a duplicate because when i searched your error message, it seems the first hit led me to a viable looking answer...

Comment: Thank you for you the answer and tips. I am going to test that.